# Chrome拡張機能にnpmモジュールを使用したい

Tags: javascript, npm, chrome-extension

Chrome拡張機能にnpmモジュールを使用することは可能でしょうか？

使用したいnpmモジュールは下記になります。

- amazon-sp-api
- aws-sdk
- qs
- crypto-js
- node-fetch
- axios

Comment: おそらくこちら [Is it possible to develop Google Chrome extensions using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12575965/9014308) の古い記事と類似と思われますが、新しい[回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69425957/9014308)が付いていて何か出来そうな感じです。他にはこんな記事が参考になるかも。[Chrome拡張の作り方 49 Webpack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5LQ7lHHs8A), [node.jsのモジュールを使ってChrome拡張機能を作る](https://qiita.com/abcang/items/10750e3fb8453d5e0944)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます!参考にさせてもらいます。